# SQL Server what to use for folio column (used to have Identity column)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table and its primary key is an identity column and I was using it as my "folio" to display its value on reports.

If an `insert` statement fails, SQL Server's default behavior is to auto-increment the seed of my identity column and because of that the user get confused when they have a report with folio 1000 and the next one is folio 1004 (because maybe 3 inserts fails).

So, what is the best way to create a folio column and manage it within a web application?

Is it a good practice that before doing a save I go to my table and get my `folio column`, auto-increment that on server side and then save it to db for the new record? I'm worried about concurrency because what happens if in the same second 2 users get the same folio number, the issue will be that I will have 2 reports with the same number.

Comment: Displaying the ID column to your users is almost always a bad practice.  If you have any sort of database problem or upgrade, all their reference numbers are screwed up.  Better to create your own id.  Put a value in another table and increment it on successful insert.

Comment: If you are using sql server 2012 or greater you can use a [sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: [Stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem!

Comment: Yes I have 2012, so with the sequence I will increment it only after successful insert right?

Comment: Yes, put it in a transaction, @marc_s makes a great point too.  Get your users use to having gaps.  They are not so big a deal.

Comment: @marc_s you have a point. :)

Comment: There are situations where no gaps and sequential numbers are of utmost importance, and in those cases neither identity or sequences are useful. Primary keys aren't one of those situations, though.